# Finding matches from an array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

`Patient` have an array of `clinician` id's that they are shared with stored in `shared_with`.  I would like to get a list of the `patients` where the current user, a clinician, has their id stored in the `patient's` `shared_with`

What I have tried to do now doesn't work:

```
@shared = Patient.find_by(shared_with: current_user.clinician.id).order("first_name asc")
```

For example, our `current_user` is associated with `clinician.id` 1 and there are `patients` with `shared_with` values of `1, 4` for `patient` 10 and `1, 7` for patient 15.  I want `@shared` to be a list with just `patient` 10 and 15.

`Patient` model:

```
Patient:
  clinician_id: integer
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  user_id: integer
  shared_with: string
  serialize :shared_with, Array
```

Patient.rb:

```
    class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :clinician
        belongs_to :user
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :user,  :allow_destroy => true
    end
```

Comment: first off, what database are you using? And your relation does not make much sense to me, as your patient `belongs_to` a clinician and at the same time `has_many` clinicians... Could you explain your models further? And what is the difference between a clinician and a patient?

Comment: Can you please confirm that `shared_with` is a string column in your database and  holds a string representation of an array like `'[1,4]'`?

Comment: database is postgres. @TheCha͢mp, `clinicians` and `patients` have many other relations with other models that I haven't shown for simplicity. A `patient` `belongs_to` their primary `clinician`, who `has_many` patients, but also has a group of other clinicians that their information needs to be `shared_with`. @spikermann, `shared_with` is a string column in your database and holds a string representation of an array like `1,4`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the Patient model doesn't need a `belongs_to` for clinicians, and doesn't need a clinician_id -- unless these are related in another fashion...in which case, carry on.

Assuming your database supports an array field (such as postgres) then you're very close.  You just need to wrap it in braces and since it's now in quotes, you'll need a #{} set for interpolation.  Like so:

```
Patient.where(shared_with: "{#{current_user.clinician.id}}").order("first_name asc")
```

Doing a test with mock modeling you provided I see this in the console:

```
2.1.1 :005 > current_user = User.first
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "benji", created_at: "2015-08-30 02:35:17", updated_at: "2015-08-30 02:35:17"> 
2.1.1 :006 > Patient.where(shared_with: "{#{current_user.clinician.id}}").order("first_name asc")
  Clinician Load (59.0ms)  SELECT  "clinicians".* FROM "clinicians"  WHERE "clinicians"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "clinicians"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Patient Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE "patients"."shared_with" = '{1}'  ORDER BY first_name asc
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Patient id: 2, clinician_id: nil, first_name: "tom", last_name: "jerry", user_id: nil, created_at: "2015-08-30 19:12:59", updated_at: "2015-08-30 19:26:37", shared_with: ["1"]>]>
```

Comment: tried that and it isn't showing anything.  In console it returns: `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> `   - an empty array

Comment: That's odd, it works for me, I outputted my console for my test.  Can you show your console output - what user is defined, what clinician that's attached to and then the patient query?  You can use a gist if it's long.

Comment: `> Patient.where(shared_with: "56")` where "56" is the `clinician.id` of a clinician that is share with a patients.  `Patient` 99 has `shared_with: 56, 57`.  I get the output: `SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE "patients"."shared_with" = '56'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: Rails 4.1.8, ruby 2.2.1p85

Comment: if I enter everything the same as you did in your edit I get: 
`Patient.where(shared_with: "{#{current_user.clinician.id}}").order("first_name asc")
  Clinician Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "clinicians".* FROM "clinicians"  WHERE "clinicians"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 223]]
  Patient Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE "patients"."shared_with" = '{74}'  ORDER BY first_name asc
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> `

Comment: What does this return: `Patient.where("? = ANY(shared_with)", 223.to_s)`

Comment: `PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
LINE 1: SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE ('223' = ANY(shar...`